# MFMailComposer sending attached Image scaled down

Tags: ios, ios5, uiimagepickercontroller, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I'm using a UIImagePicker to take a picture and browse the Camera Roll.. I also added a link to mail the picture which is displayed in a popup window.  The attached image comes up in it's native size (which is pretty enormous).  What I want to do is scale down that image.. but only for the MFMailComposer's view.  When send is selected I want the full image to be sent.

Answer (score 0):

The attachment can only be specified *before* showing the MFMailComposer view and that's the attachment it will show. Usually, it tries to fit the image within the bounds of MFMailComposer view.

Do you mean to say you have to scroll left, right and bottom to view the complete image ?

Comment: my mfmailcomposer is in a popover.  I want it to essentially be much smaller (aka thumbnail sized).

Comment: I'm afraid that's not possible. You would need to attach the file that you want to send and it's upto MFMailComposer view how it wants to display that type.